# Getting integer values to array from file

Tags: java, arrays, filereader

I am trying to get integer values by seperated commas from a file and putting them into an 2d array.
File is like this;

```
0,7,9,0,0,14
7,0,10,15,0,0
9,10,0,11,0,2
0,15,11,0,6,0
0,0,0,6,0,9
14,0,2,0,9,0
```

so i want first line to be in array[0][0 to 5] and same for other lines as well, for example array[2][1] must be 10. But i can't figure out the algorithm of 2d array here at all.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(reader);
    int[][] array = new int[6][6];

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] str = line.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    array[i][j] = Integer.valueOf(str[i]);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through every value for each line. One of your indices needs to be the line and the other needs to be the position within the line. You only need one `for` loop; you should increment the other index as part of your while loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(reader);
    int[][] array = new int[6][6];
    int i=0;
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] str = line.split(",");
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            array[i][j] = Integer.valueOf(str[j]);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

You should also consider that if the file has more than 6 lines or more than 6 rows, this will fail, so this is not very robust code. You may be better off populating a different(dynamic) data type and converting to an array once you are done reading the file. At a minimum, you should check that you are not exceeding the expected range of the indices.

Comment: It was actually a steady 81x81 matrix in file but i wanted to make a prototype with 6x6 matrix here. Your code works and 2d array holds the values, Now i gotta use them to find shortest paths ones between neighbour ones. I didn't understand what you said at last because i am new at programming, so the code you shared would work for my project or please can you tell me what must i use with more spesifics ?

Comment: The code will work as is, it just has limitations. Since you're really dealing with a matrix here, the fixed indices probably do make sense. To address the problem of the indices being out of bounds, just add that to the conditions. For instance on your while loop, you can do `while(sc.hasNextLine()&&i<6)`. You would need a similar condition in your for loop. If there are fewer than 6 comma-separated values, `str[j]` is going to throw an exception since `j` wont exist. As far as other data types, I was thinking something like `ArrayList`. Since you have fixed values, the primitive array is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.  The key point is that there are no real multi-dimensional arrays in Java.   Just single D arrays that can also hold arrays.

```
        // allocate the "2D" array but no need to specify the rows.
        int[][] array = new int[6][];

        // starting row number
        int rowNumber = 0;

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] str = line.split(",");

            // here is where your code differs
            // allocate a new row based on length of items just read
            int[] row = new int[str.length];

            // Now copy and convert to ints.
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                row[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
            }
            // Then just assign the row to the row number.
            // you can do this because a two dimentional array is just an
            // one dimenional array of another one dimensional array.
            array[rowNumber++] = row;
        }
        // print them out for verification.
        // get each row (from the array of rows)
        for (int[] row : array) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
```

So what did was just like the following;

```
int [][] matrix = new int[2][];
matrix[0] = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
// rows can be different sizes.
matrix[1] = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};      

for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {
   int[] row  = matrix[i];
   for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(row[j] + " " );
   }
   System.out.println(); // next line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more modern way of doing it, using [NIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)) and [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
int[][] read2dArrayFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path))
                .stream()
                .map(line ->
                         Arrays.stream(
                             line.split("\\D+")  // split by anything that's not a digit
                         ).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()
                ).toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```